# Why am I facing this TypeError in Angular unit testing?

Tags: angular, typescript, typeerror, ag-grid

```
this.columnDefs.forEach((columnDef) => {
  columnDef.floatingFilter = this.hasFloatingFilter;
});
this.gridApi.setColumnDefs(this.columnDefs);
```

ERROR: 'ERROR', TypeError: this.gridApi.setColumnDefs is not a function
TypeError: this.gridApi.setColumnDefs is not a function

I have declared a variable gridApi of type GridApi from 'ag-grid-community'.
Even though setColumnDefs() is a function. On unit testing, I find the above mentioned error.

Comment: If this is a unit test, what is `this`, and where is the code you have shared placed?

Comment: You should add your code, at least the whole test block and where gridApi is defined.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order for ag-grid plugin to work, both in unit tests and in feature code, `AgGridModule` must be imported. Did you add it to the `imports` array in your `TestBed` setup?

```
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    import: [
      AgGridModule  
    ],
    declarations: [
      ComponentToTest,
    ],
    ...

  }).compileComponents();
```